# CupertinoTabBar not showing anything in dark mode

Tags: flutter, dart

Run the official demo at this page in dark mode: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabBar-class.html

It shows nothing, it only works in light mode.

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code-snippet here?

Answer (score 0):

Those code snippets run over Flutter for Web and each project takes the details from your system for the theme if it is not defined the otherway around.

You can fix it in two ways:

1. You can change your theme on the device to light mode
2. You can add the theme type to the CupertinoApp like below:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const CupertinoApp(
      theme: CupertinoThemeData(
         brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
```

Each will show the following

[image]